# How can I select columns in a Pandas DataFrame by datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of a standard shape:

```
   A     B     C       D        E................φ
1-Int   NaN Str Obj  Datetime  NaN..........Mixed Obj (like currency)
2-NaN Float Str Obj  Datetime Category..........NaN
3-Int Float   NaN    Datetime Category......Mixed Obj
.  .   .       .         .       .               .
.  .   .       .         .       .               .
.  .   .       .         .       .               .
Z-Int Float Str Obj     NaN   Category......Mixed Obj
```

In the example above, Z is an arbitrary row greater than 3. Φ is an arbitrary column name that represents a column greater than C. It could be the 90th column or the 150th column. My aim is to sift through the columns above replace values NaN values by datatype. My desired outcome is this:

```
   A     B     C       D        E......................φ
1-Int  0.00 Str Obj  Datetime Uncategorized.......Mixed Obj
2- 0  Float Str Obj  Datetime Category...............$0.00
3-Int Float  "None"  Datetime Category............Mixed Obj
.  .   .       .         .       .                     .
.  .   .       .         .       .                     .
.  .   .       .         .       .                     .
Z-Int Float Str Obj  0/00/0000 Category...........Mixed Obj
```

The goal is to have the ability to replace NaN values in specific columns which contain specific datatypes, with their datatype's version of 0. So 0 for integer, 0.00 for float, "None" for string, 0/00/0000 for Datetime (I know this may cause some problems), uncategorized for category, and $0.00 for mixed objects like currency.

To attempt this, I used pandas loc function to see if I could locate column by column is this were true.

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(df.loc[:,col].apply(isinstance, args = [int]))
```

The expected result was:

```
   A     
1-True   
2-False 
3-True  
.  .    
.  .  
.  .   
Z-True
```

However I got:

```
   A     
1-False   
2-False 
3-False  
.  .    
.  .  
.  .   
Z-False
```

I don't understand why I couldn't identify the integers inside of this column.

Comment: You might consider running `df[col].apply(type)` to see what type of data actually is in your frame if they're not int.

Comment: @HenryEcker. Congratulations for your 20k :-)

Comment: @HenryEcker I see what you mean. It is applying the datatype to the frame work. My aim was to isolate int values.

Comment: I understand but I just wanted to confirm that they were actually of type `int` and not strings that look like ints or any other int-like type.

Comment: @HenryEcker this column returns a value of `int64` when I run `df[col].dtype`. So now, I don't believe it's a string-like or int-like object. Though some columns that should be returning as date do appear to be return as string objects.

Comment: `isinstance(np.int64(1), int)` returns `False`. Maybe you should be checking against `np.int64` instead of int? You might also add an executable DataFrame constructor to your question so we have something we can create exactly the Data you're working with.

Comment: @HenryEcker my datetime data is returning like string like objects, as well as some columns that have floats. Is there a way to look inside of the cell and check if it is of the format '\d+' or 'f\+'?

Comment: @HenryEcker I understand the context of your comment. I have to look for Pandas particular datasets, understood.

Comment: Given the answer you've accepted, I've linked to another question which has many more options that may also be helpful depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to get only the columns in a dataframe that match a specific type. For example, to get just the float columns you'd use:

```
df.select_dtypes(include='float64')
```

The `include` argument takes a string or list so you can specify multiple types if you want.